# vhost showing default wamp page

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

I am using wamp to build my web application. So I had one vhost at mydomain.com but now I have changed my domain to dev.mydomain.com . For this changes to reflect I have edited `etc\hosts` file's entry from `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com`to `127.0.0.1 dev.mydomain.com` and in apache configuration file `httpd-vhosts.conf` -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/Software/Installed/wamp/www/myapp/public"
 ServerName dev.mydomain.com
 <Directory  "D:/Software/Installed/wamp/www/myapp">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
 </Directory>
```

When I open url `dev.mydomain.com`, I see the default wamp config page.

I have gone through many tutorials to find out what mistakes have been done but could find none. It would be helpful if someone throws some light on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your **Directory** different than **DocumentRoot** ??

I think you need to match those and restart your wamp and you are good to go.

Also, you must have index file in directory to see domain running properly.